# Authenticate User on Active Directory in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, form-authentication

I want to make a web application that enable employee to access company server remotely from his laptop using an authentication to active directory

I have found this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx

I want to implement it on my local machine first, I want to enter domain which is my localserver and my user account data (username and password) and then authenticate myself to use the web application

When I entered My Domain : http://localhost:5000
Username : AMIRA --> The user that I'm using in windows
and My Password

I got the error
Error authenticating. Error authenticating user. Unspecified error

Please if anyone know how to configure it or solve this problem I will be thankful

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the windows authentications to allow application check with active directory users and I suggest to use actual IIS not the build in one with MS.Net and try to access remotely to site on the local machine to test it (using your PC IP address)

regards,